# Under android, Can i do Settings.Secure.getInt() from a background thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-thread

under android, can i run the code below :

```
int locationMode = Settings.Secure.getInt(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE, Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_HIGH_ACCURACY);
```

from a background thread (not from the main ui thread) ?

Comment: AFAIK, yes. Under the covers, it's just using `ContentResolver` to query a `ContentProvider`. Did you run into problems when you tried it?

Comment: If  you for some reason wouldn't be able to, you can get an activity instance and use runOnUiThread

Comment: thanks, no right now i just want to know if it's work in theory... i try it's didn't crash, but didn't crash not mean it's work ;)